# How to quickly produce statsmodels Rolling OLS residuals for each time period?

Tags: python, statsmodels

The RollingOLS docs suggest there is a .resid parameter: https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.html

However, I don't see that param popping up as an option when I use my tab key to autocomplete, and when I type it in I get this error:
AttributeError: 'RollingRegressionResults' object has no attribute 'resid'

How do I call/save the residuals of a fitted rollingOLS model?

Answer (score 0):

Given a model as described under the Rolling Regression [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/rolling_ls.html) by statsmodels:

```
rols = RollingOLS(endog, exog, window=60)
rres = rols.fit()
```

The residuals can be calculated as follows:

```
rolling_resid = endog - (rres.params * exog).sum(1)
rolling_resid
```

The above example uses the *F-F_Research_Data_Factors* dataset as a template, and the model output illustrates the residuals as below:

```
Date
1926-07    2.680000
1926-08    2.410000
1926-09   -0.610000
1926-10   -4.900000
1926-11    4.400000
             ...   
2023-01    1.893907
2023-02    1.957900
2023-03    6.838132
2023-04   -1.063139
2023-05    6.997906
Freq: M, Length: 1163, dtype: float64
```

Please also see the following [GitHub](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/7521) guide for further information.